# How to split a list of complex objects into specific length similar to chunklist in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

Consider this

```
locals {
    raw = [{a = 1}, {b = 2}, {c = 3}, {d = 4}, {e = 5}, {f = 6}, {g = 7}, {h = 8},]
    chunk_size = 3
}
```

I got for `chunklist(local.raw, local.chunk_size)`

```
│ Invalid value for "list" parameter: all list elements must have the same type.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can slice the input manually

```
locals {
    raw = [{a = 1}, {b = 2}, {c = 3}, {d = 4}, {e = 5}, {f = 6}, {g = 7}, {h = 8},]
    chunk_size = 3
}

output "chunklist_for_complex_object_list" {
    value = [
        for i, each in local.raw:
        slice(
            local.raw, i,
            i + local.chunk_size >= length(local.raw) ?
            length(local.raw) : i + local.chunk_size
        )
        if (i % local.chunk_size == 0)
    ]
}
```

Output:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + chunklist_for_complex_object_list = [
      + [
          + {
              + a = 1
            },
          + {
              + b = 2
            },
          + {
              + c = 3
            },
        ],
      + [
          + {
              + d = 4
            },
          + {
              + e = 5
            },
          + {
              + f = 6
            },
        ],
      + [
          + {
              + g = 7
            },
          + {
              + h = 8
            },
        ],
    ]
```